# identify the page load successful on the server side java

Tags: java

I am preparing a program in java and its purpose is to make the HttpWebRequest for a url which can open in any browser (i am planning to use watij for opening the page in different browser).Now my program should take the screen shot of the presently opened url once the page has loaded successfully.I need to run a piece of code after the browser has loaded successfully in the browser.I dont want to use the javascript document.ready function for identifying if the page is loaded successfully or not.I should be able to know the page load complete status in the server side (s0 that i can execute that piece of code for taking the screenshot).How can i do it in java.Or is there any other  way to do achieve that if its not possible in java.May be create some plugins.

An early reply is highly valued,
Regards,Sagar.

Comment: Do you control the pages that you want to take a snapshot of? If you don't, then you might run into trouble with pages using Ajax to load.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using applet, [just taking snapshot i meant that you want.]